# Joomla!2.5 component ported to J!3.3: toolbar not working

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla3.3

While adapting a Joomla!2.5 backend-only component to Joomla!3.3, I've ran into the issue of the toolbar in the data edition page not working at all. Only two buttons were declared: Save and Cancel; neither do anything. Upon first glance, the problem is neither on the *view.html.php* file, nor *tmpl/edit.php*. This very component is already being used in our current Joomla!2.5 website and works perfectly.

All control, model and view pages have already been updated to *JControllerLegacy*, *JModelLegacy* and *JViewLegacy* respectively, where applicable.

***view.html.php***

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
jimport('joomla.application.component.viewlegacy');

class MrCarrosselNoticiasViewMrCarrosselNoticias extends JViewLegacy {
    function display($tpl = null){
        $form = $this->get('Form');
        $item = $this->get('Item');
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))){
            JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
            return false;
        }
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->addToolBar();
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

    protected function addToolBar(){
        $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
        $isNew = ($this->item->cod_destaque == 0);
        JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? "Novo Destaque" : "Editando Destaque");
        JToolBarHelper::save('mrcarrosselnoticias.save');
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('mrcarrosselnoticias.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL');
    }
}
```